# Draw a line from 2D Label to a point in 3D Space in VTK

Tags: c#, vtk

I am working with 3D visualisation using VTK. I would like a attach a line between a point in 3D space to fixed label (in 2D space) on VTKRenderWindow.

I have no idea what possibly I can do. Any hint on that would be much appreciated.

If someone has worked with Polyworks than it would be exactly something like that.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to use a `vtkFollower` object and `vtkFollower.SetCamera(vtkCamera)`
(see [here](https://github.com/ismarou/vtkplotter-examples/blob/master/vtkplotter_examples/pyplot/markpoint.py)).

[image]